# Redirect only when the parent is directly addressed

Tags: ember.js

This is my code:

```
App.Router.map(function () {

    ....

    this.resource('profile', function () {
        this.route('user');
        this.route('user.edit', { path: '/:user_id/edit' });
        this.route('password');
        this.route('company');
        this.route('company.edit', { path: '/:company_id/edit' });
        this.resource('products', function () {
            this.route('index');
            this.route('show',   { path: '/:product_id/show' });
        });
    });

    ....

});

App.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo('profile.user');
    }
});
```

And I have a `link-to`:

```
{{#link-to "products.index" }}<i class="icon-barcode icon-2x pull-left icon-border"></i>{{/link-to}}
```

Which is linking to `#/profile/products/index`. But this triggers the redirect in `ProfileRoute`, which is not desired: the redirect should **only** be triggered whenever `#/profile` or `#/profile/index` is accessed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from `App.ProfileRoute` to `App.ProfileIndexRoute`. Like the following:

```
App.ProfileIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo('profile.user');
    }
});
```

`App.ProductsRoute` have as parent the `App.ProfileRoute` route, so the `redirect` (a.k.a beforeModel), is triggered, and you get your undesired behavior. Using `App.ProfileIndexRoute` fixes it, because the `App.ProfileIndexRoute` is just triggered when calling `/profile`

I hope it helps